# "CouldNotFindSpotifyApp" exception thrown on the Google Play uploaded version of my app

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, spotify, spotify-app

I have made an app with the spotify-app-remote SDK and it works perfectly.

But when I upload it to Google Play and download it from there, it crashes and throws *CouldNotFindSpotifyApp* exception.

Does the Google Play processing change something in the apk?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by downgrading the spotify-app-remote.

Finally...